# How to fix the image on the right?

Tags: android

I am creating custom `ActionBar` and I have `RelativeLayut` with two images and text. I want the second `ImageView`  to be fixed to the right, but I can not do it. It shifts depending on the screen resolution. How can I solve this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="mAPP"
        android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_title_text_size"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which `ImageView`? The one with id `image` or `icon`? Also please go through some tutorial about `RelativeLayout`. It seems you have some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="mAPP"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_title_text_size" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_text"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I have changed is the parent layout to `LinearLayout` then gave weights to its children, that's all.

Comment: Please also explain what you did so it is not spoon-feeding for the OP.

Comment: how to save same size?

Comment: What you mean by same size? you mean the height of your parent layout? or its children?

Comment: I mean size image, he became much less than it was. Height and width.

Comment: You may need to manually set the height for the ImageView with the id: `image`. For example: 48dp